# Trying to retrieve discord.js server owner name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so when I use this code in other servers, I get an error. In my own server, I do not. I am still rather new to discord.js and node.js in general while getting my hands dirty with promises and stuff like that. This is my first post :)  Here is the code:

```
else if(message2 === `${prefix} si`) {
    

     var serv = ()=> {
        
          message.guild.fetch(message.guild.id)
          
          
          
          .then((response) => {


            const serverWho = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(' #a6f7e4 ')
            .setTitle(message.guild.name)
            .setImage(message.guild.iconURL())
            .addFields(
                
                
                {name: "First Created:",value: message.guild.createdAt.toDateString(),inline: true},
                {name:"Members", value: message.guild.memberCount, inline: true}, //will implement member count without bots soon
                {name: '\u200B', value : '\u200B', inline:true},
                {name: "Owner:", value: response.owner.user.username.toString(), inline:true}
                );
            
            message.channel.send(serverWho);
         
        
        })
        


        }
        
        serv();

    
        
   }
```

The error is saying something like "cannot read property of user" of null.
Again, this error only occurs in other servers besides the one I own. Thank you for you help! If you need any more information, please feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using discord.js v12?

Comment: Yes I am using discord.js v 12

Comment: I will try to work out that solution, thank you Shoejep. I'll keep u updated.